# get the number of parents that equal to the sum of children

Tags: sum, children

i have a problem with the below code. i need to get the number of parents that it's value = to the sum of it's 2 children. example if parent value = 10 and its children are 2 and 8. 
    then i have to count this parent as 1. i need to check for all nodes in the tree.

```
this is what i tried to do: could you please advise:


int BinaryTree::numberOfSum (){
return numberOfSumImpl (root);
}
int BinaryTree::numberOfSumImpl (BTNode *rootNode, int el){
    if(rootNode ==0) return 0;
    int count=0;
        if(rootNode->hasTwoChildren() || rootNode->isLeaf()) 
        else if{
            if (rootNode->info==el) return count=1;
        return count + numberOfSumImpl(el,rootNode->left) + numberOfSumImpl(el,rootNode->right);
        }
}


Many Thanks,
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a few problems with the call to `numberOfSumImpl`, as in the main function it is only called with one parameter, and in the recursive function it is called with two parameters, but with the order inversed. This code does not even compile!

Besides, the condition `rootNode->hasTwoChildren() || rootNode->isLeaf())` looks strange and, having its body empty even more strange.

You did not post the definition of the `BTNode`, but looks like you are looking for something as

```
int BinaryTree::numberOfSumImpl (BTNode* p) {
    if (not p) return 0;
    int count;
    if (p->hasTwoChildren() and p->info == p->left->info + p->right->info) {
        count = 1;
    } else {
        count = 0;
    }
    return count + numberOfSumImpl(p->left) + numberOfSumImpl(p->right);
}
```

And this function would possibly be `static`.

Comment: yes, this is what i am looking for to get the sum of both childrens and see if the total = to parent value then count it. otherwise return null or zero.